# Is it ok to screw nesting boxes to trees?

Tags: trees, birds

I have a bunch of nesting boxes for small birds I am putting up. I am just wondering what is the best way to attach the boxes to various trees. I have seen screws used but I am not sure about that. I think it may damage the tree.

Answer (score 5):

One screw wont hurt the tree. Just be sure to use a stainless steel screw so it doesn't rust out and break off in the tree.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest risk is to the lumber yard that cuts the tree for lumber; The steel nails and screws are bad for the cutting tools. My lot was formerly fenced with barb wire , trying to get the wire out where the tree has grown over it is a large problem . I have lost a number of hooks , etc, that I put in after the trees have overgrown them. It happens relatively fast ( at least for an old person ). This reminds me , I have some hammock hooks I need to check. I have read that a few copper nails / screws can kill a tree, but I never tried it.

Comment: That's a good point. I had a mature Ash tree that fell down and I asked if the local saw mill would be interested in taking it. The guy said that he wouldn't as I wouldn't be able to guarantee there were no nails in it. This tree was over 100 years old so someone may have put nails in there years before. The saws in the mill were so expensive that a nail could ruin it, so it wasn't worth it.